# Laravel: Mediable migration error Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im new to Laravel, trying to use Laravel mediable package but it gives me an error on migration -> "[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `media` add unique `media_disk_directory_filen
  ame_extension_unique`(`disk`, `directory`, `filename`, `extension`))

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes"

Im on Laravel 5.4.36, the solution on other sites is to add this ->

```
 public function boot()
    {
        //
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

but i already have this in my project.

can anybody please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to fix this by canging `engine` value in `config/database.php` config file:

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
```

If you want to use this fix:

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Make sure you've registered this service provider in `config/app.php`

Answer (score 0):

this work with me, 
Inside config/database.php
i replace this 
'engine' => null',
with :
engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',

this solution Instead of setting a limit on your string lenght.